# How to create multiple Treeview window with same format/layout upon clicking a button in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, treeview, ttk

Currently I have one window that displays two Treeview frames(festo and transformer) that of identical layout. These treeview layout should display different user data from txt files. Hence, the no of Treeview windows are dynamic based on the no txt files in a folder. Is it possible to create/generate multiple pop-up Treeview windows of the same layout upon a button click?

[image: Current single window]

```
class HomePage(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()  # Create a notebook widget
        self.add_tab1()
        #self.add_tab2()
        self.notebook.grid(row=0)
        self.notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    def add_tab1(self):
        tab1 = tab_one(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(tab1, text="Home")

    def add_tab2(self):
        tab2 = ttk.Notebook()
        self.notebook.add(tab2, text="Reports")


class data_table(object):
    def __init__(self, site, panels_count, tev_count):
        self.site = site
        self.panels_count = panels_count
        self.tev_count = tev_count


class tab_one(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Creating frames on the window/canvas for the first tab
        frame_selectfile = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Step 1: Zip File Extraction ", bd=6)  # Frame1 on the window/canvas
        frame_selectfile.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')  # Positioning frame1
        frame_selectfile.configure(borderwidth=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Configuring the column for the main window/canvas
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Configuring the row for the main window/canvas

        frame_checkpd = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Step 2: Check PD ", bd=6)  # Frame2 on the window/canvas
        frame_checkpd.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')  # Positioning frame2
        frame_checkpd.configure(borderwidth=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the column for the main window/canvas
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the row for the main window/canvas
        
        frame_festo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Festo: ", bd=6)  # Frame1 on the window/canvas
        frame_festo.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')  # Positioning frame1
        frame_festo.configure(borderwidth=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the column for the main window/canvas
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the row for the main window/canvas
        
        frame_transform = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Transformer: ", bd=6)  # Frame1 on the window/canvas
        frame_transform.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')  # Positioning frame1
        frame_transform.configure(borderwidth=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the column for the main window/canvas
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Configuring the row for the main window/canvas

        # Initializing all variables in frame_selectfile
        file_ID = tk.StringVar()
        file_ID2 = tk.StringVar()
        location_id = tk.StringVar()
        location_id2 = tk.StringVar()
        unzip_status = tk.StringVar()
        tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().name
        #self.create_dir_ifnot_exist(tmpdir)
        zip_filename = tk.StringVar()
        site_id = tk.StringVar()
        site_id.set("0")
        data_table_list = []
        file_counter = tk.StringVar()
        
        # Initializing all variables in frame_festo
        festo_date_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_job_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_engineer_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_station_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_voltage_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_db_id = tk.StringVar()
        festo_pd_id = tk.StringVar()
        
        # Initializing all variables in frame_transform
        transform_date_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_job_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_engineer_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_station_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_voltage_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_db_id = tk.StringVar()
        transform_pd_id = tk.StringVar()
        
        topframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame_festo, bd=0)
        
        topframe_transform = tk.LabelFrame(frame_transform, bd=0)
        
        middleframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame_selectfile, bd=5)
        
        databaseView = ttk.Treeview(middleframe, selectmode="browse")
        
        #label_filename = tk.Label(frame_selectfile, text=" ", width=10, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_filelocation = tk.Label(frame_selectfile, text="File Location:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')

        filename_Entry = tk.Label(frame_selectfile, width=52, textvariable=file_ID)
        filename_Entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        filename_Entry.configure(state='normal')

        filelocation_Entry = tk.Entry(frame_selectfile, width=60, textvariable=location_id)
        filelocation_Entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')
        filelocation_Entry.configure(background='palegreen', foreground='black')

        middleframe2 = tk.LabelFrame(frame_festo, bd=5)
        databaseView2 = ttk.Treeview(middleframe2, selectmode="browse")
        
        transform_middle_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame_transform, bd=5)
        
        transformView = ttk.Treeview(transform_middle_frame, selectmode="browse")
        #label_filename2 = tk.Label(topframe, text=" ", width=10, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        
        #label_filelocation2 = tk.Label(topframe, text="File Location:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        
        label_festo_date_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Scanned Date:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_festo_job_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Job No:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_festo_engineer_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Engineer:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=4, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_festo_station_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Station:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')
        label_festo_voltage_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Operating Voltage(kV):", width=18, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_festo_db_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Max dB:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        #label_festo_pd_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Max PD:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        
        festo_date_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_date_id)
        festo_date_id_Entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_date_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        
        festo_job_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_job_id)
        festo_job_id_Entry.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_job_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        
        festo_engineer_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_engineer_id)
        festo_engineer_id_Entry.grid(column=5, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_engineer_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')       
        
        festo_station_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_station_id)
        festo_station_id_Entry.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_station_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')        
        
        festo_voltage_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_voltage_id)
        festo_voltage_id_Entry.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_voltage_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')        
        
        festo_db_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe, width=15, textvariable=festo_db_id)
        festo_db_id_Entry.grid(column=5, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        festo_db_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        
        
        label_transform_date_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Scanned Date:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_transform_job_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Job No:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_transform_engineer_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Engineer:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=4, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_transform_station_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Station:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_transform_voltage_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Operating Voltage(kV):", width=18, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        label_transform_db_id = tk.Label(topframe_transform, text="Max dB:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        #label_transform_pd_id = tk.Label(topframe, text="Max PD:", width=12, relief='flat').grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        
        transform_date_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_date_id)
        transform_date_id_Entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_date_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        
        transform_job_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_job_id)
        transform_job_id_Entry.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_job_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        
        transform_engineer_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_engineer_id)
        transform_engineer_id_Entry.grid(column=5, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_engineer_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')       
        
        transform_station_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_station_id)
        transform_station_id_Entry.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_station_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')        
        
        transform_voltage_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_voltage_id)
        transform_voltage_id_Entry.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_voltage_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')        
        
        transform_db_id_Entry = tk.Entry(topframe_transform, width=15, textvariable=transform_db_id)
        transform_db_id_Entry.grid(column=5, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NW')
        transform_db_id_Entry.configure(state='normal')
        

        unzip_status.set("")
        label_unzipstatus = tk.Label(frame_selectfile, width=20, relief='flat', textvariable=unzip_status)
        label_unzipstatus.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NSEW')

        selectzip_button = tk.Button(frame_selectfile, width=20, text="Select Zip File", command=lambda: self.upload_action(location_id, zip_filename, tmpdir))
        selectzip_button.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=3, ipady=3, sticky='SW')

        unzip_button = tk.Button(frame_selectfile, width=20, text="Extract", command=lambda: self.extract_nested_zip(databaseView, data_table_list, location_id.get(), tmpdir, zip_filename, site_id, False))
        unzip_button.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=3, ipady=3, sticky='NE')

        # Creating LabelFrame in frame_unzip
        upperframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame_selectfile, bd=0)
        frame_selectfile.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame_selectfile.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        upperframe.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=2, sticky='W')

        # middleframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame_selectfile, bd=5)
        middleframe.configure(borderwidth=1)
        frame_selectfile.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame_selectfile.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        middleframe.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        
        middleframe2.configure(borderwidth=1)
        frame_festo.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame_festo.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        middleframe2.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        
        transform_middle_frame.configure(borderwidth=1)
        frame_transform.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame_transform.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        transform_middle_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")

#         lowerframe = tk.LabelFrame(frame_selectfile, bd=0)
#         lowerframe.grid(column=0, row=7)
#         frame_selectfile.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
#         frame_selectfile.rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        
        
        topframe.configure(borderwidth=1)
        frame_festo.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame_festo.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        topframe.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        
        
        topframe_transform.configure(borderwidth=1)
        frame_transform.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        frame_transform.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        topframe_transform.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")

        # Labels in frame_unzip
        label18 = tk.Label(upperframe, text="Number of sites:", relief='flat')
        label18.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='W')

        site_Entry = tk.Entry(upperframe, width=45, textvariable=site_id)
        site_Entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='E')
        site_Entry.configure(state='normal', background='palegreen', foreground='black')

        # Button Widgets in frame_unzip
        #unzip_btn = tk.Button(upperframe, width=10, text="Unzip File", command=lambda: Unzip(databaseview))
        #unzip_btn.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=0, pady=5, ipady=2, sticky='E')

#         label_details = tk.Label(upperframe, text=" ", relief='flat')
#         label_details.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=5, pady=0, sticky='W')
        # Combobox Widgets in frame_unzip

        # initializing treeview in frame_unzip
        # databaseView = ttk.Treeview(middleframe, selectmode="browse")
        databaseView.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        databaseView.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        
        databaseView2.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        databaseView2.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")

        transformView.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        transformView.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NSEW")
        
        # Creating treeview in frame_unzip
        vsb = Scrollbar(middleframe, orient="vertical", command=databaseView.yview())
        hsb = Scrollbar(middleframe, orient="horizontal")
        
        vsb = Scrollbar(middleframe2, orient="vertical", command=databaseView2.yview())
        hsb = Scrollbar(middleframe2, orient="horizontal")
        
        vsb = Scrollbar(transform_middle_frame, orient="vertical", command=transformView.yview())
        hsb = Scrollbar(transform_middle_frame, orient="horizontal")

        middleframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        middleframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        databaseView["show"] = "headings"
        databaseView["columns"] = ("site", "panels", "tevs")
        vsb.configure(command=databaseView.yview)
        # hsb.configure(command=databaseView.xview)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="NS")
        # hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="WE")
        
        middleframe2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        middleframe2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        databaseView2["show"] = "headings"
        databaseView2["columns"] = ("num", "name", "component", "location", "phase", "db", "prpd", "pulse", "pd")
        vsb.configure(command=databaseView2.yview)
        # hsb.configure(command=databaseView.xview)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="NS")
        
        transform_middle_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        transform_middle_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        transformView["show"] = "headings"
        transformView["columns"] = ("num", "name", "component", "location", "phase", "db", "prpd", "pulse", "pd")
        vsb.configure(command=transformView.yview)
        # hsb.configure(command=databaseView.xview)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="NS")

        # Treeview column headings
        databaseView.heading("site", text="Site")
        databaseView.column("site", anchor='w', width=250)
        databaseView.heading("panels", text="Number of Panels")
        databaseView.column("panels", anchor='center', width=100)
        databaseView.heading("tevs", text="Number of TEVs")
        databaseView.column("tevs", anchor='center', width=100)
        
        # Treeview column headings festo
        databaseView2.heading("num", text="Panel")
        databaseView2.column("num", anchor='w', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("name", text="Tev")
        databaseView2.column("name", anchor='center', width=150)
        databaseView2.heading("component", text="Component")
        databaseView2.column("component", anchor='center', width=150)
        databaseView2.heading("location", text="Sublocation")
        databaseView2.column("location", anchor='w', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("phase", text="Phase Ref Lock")
        databaseView2.column("phase", anchor='center', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("db", text="dB")
        databaseView2.column("db", anchor='center', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("prpd", text="PRPD")
        databaseView2.column("prpd", anchor='w', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("pulse", text="Pulse Wave")
        databaseView2.column("pulse", anchor='center', width=100)
        databaseView2.heading("pd", text="PD%")
        databaseView2.column("pd", anchor='center', width=100)
        
        # Treeview column headings transform
        transformView.heading("num", text="Panel")
        transformView.column("num", anchor='w', width=100)
        transformView.heading("name", text="Tev")
        transformView.column("name", anchor='center', width=150)
        transformView.heading("component", text="Component")
        transformView.column("component", anchor='center', width=150)
        transformView.heading("location", text="Sublocation")
        transformView.column("location", anchor='w', width=100)
        transformView.heading("phase", text="Phase Ref Lock")
        transformView.column("phase", anchor='center', width=100)
        transformView.heading("db", text="dB")
        transformView.column("db", anchor='center', width=100)
        transformView.heading("prpd", text="PRPD")
        transformView.column("prpd", anchor='w', width=100)
        transformView.heading("pulse", text="Pulse Wave")
        transformView.column("pulse", anchor='center', width=100)
        transformView.heading("pd", text="PD%")
        transformView.column("pd", anchor='center', width=100)

        # Widgets in Frame 3
        #label_checkstatus = tk.Label(frame_checkpd, text="Status", width=5, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='E')
        #label_checkstatuscolour = tk.Label(frame_checkpd, text=" ", bg="limegreen", width=5, relief='flat').grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='E')

        findpd_btn = tk.Button(frame_checkpd, width=20, text="Find PDs", command=lambda: self.run_pd_model_exe(tmpdir, zip_filename))
        findpd_btn.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='E')
        export_pdf_btn = tk.Button(frame_checkpd, width=20, text="Export to PDF",
                               command=lambda: self.export_to_pdf(tmpdir, zip_filename))
        export_pdf_btn.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='E')
        
        
        file_counter = 0
        
        find_files_btn = tk.Button(frame_checkpd, width=20, text="Check Files", command=lambda: self.check_files(file_counter, find_files_btn))
        find_files_btn.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NSEW')
        
        print(file_counter)
        
        file_counter = 0

        #selectzip_button.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=3, ipady=3, sticky='SW')

        
        
    def check_files(self, counter, btn):
        
        
        # folder path
        dir_path = r'C:\Users\Documents\GUI\input_folder'
        count = 0
        # Iterate directory
        for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
        # check if current path is a file
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
                count += 1
        print('File count:', count)
        return count
```

Comment: What if there are several 100 txt files? Then, do we spawn several treeview windows? Is there a limit?

Comment: hi @amanb, typically it would be between 1-10, based on the folder given by user. But the problem is that it's dynamic, so I could not figure out the best logic/way to display this. The pop-up treeview sounded like a plausible alternative. Not sure if this is possible as a separate tab e.g. Home, Tab_txt1, Tab_txt2...Tab_txt10

Comment: Of course you can write a function that creates as many treeview widgets that you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm getting an error when running your code: `NameError: name 'tempfile' is not defined`

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, I am not sure on how to convert/duplicate this treeview to produce multiple times. Do you think this would be a good way to visualize multiple windows?

Comment: @amanb pls comment out those lines